# Git - pushing same commit again after closing incorrect Pull Request

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I want to re-push the same commits ( without changes ) from Intellij.

I closed the existing PR and deleted the branch because the target branch was incorrect.

What is the shortest, quickest way to re-push the commits / fix the Pr with proper target branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Base branch can be changed on the existing PR , by clicking "Edit" next to the PR Title, and in the 'base branch' drop-down select the prpoer branch ..

https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/changing-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request

Answer (score 0):

There is no "repush". All pushes are the same. In IntelliJ you can press Ctrl+Shift+K and then press Ctrl+Enter.

For future reference, don't delete the branch to fix the PR. On GitHub, close the PR and then create a new one with the existing branch. On BitBucket, you don't even need to close the PR. Just click Edit and then select a new target branch.

Comment: i actually found that you can change the base branch on a pull request : https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/changing-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request. Adding this as an answer.

Comment: @Jcoder That sounds like a new-ish feature. I haven't used GitHub very much over the last year or so. Thanks for pointing it out.